# Bounty not awarded after the end of the grace period?

Tags: support, bounties

The bounty to one of my answers wasn't awarded to me when the user that asked the question accepted my answer 2 days before it ended. What would be the reason for this to happen?

This is the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274412/english-dictionaries-and-thesaurus-for-net-applications/12396061#12396061

The notice says:

> This question had a bounty worth +[x] reputation from [user] that ended yesterday. Grace period has ended

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It takes some time for the system to auto-award the bounty. It's only listing that the grace period has expired. It **has not** yet determined if the bounty should be auto-awarded. When the time comes, it should award it to you, assuming that the OP accepted your answer during the bounty period.

**Easiest way to think about it:** if the bounty notice is still present on the question, the system hasn't decided yet. When it does decide, it will remove the bounty notice.

Comment: I got half of the bounty after the notice is removed, and the OP accepted it after the expiry will the system give the remaining 150 or only the normal accepted reputation?

Comment: @RajendranNadar reputation from the bounty is only given once (or none at all). There's no follow-up reputation when the criteria are fulfilled afterward.

Comment: What is the maximum amount of time after the end of the grace period, that the bounty would take to get auto-awarded?

Comment: @user1271772 looks like it's about one hour. (There's hourly job running, that look for bounties that ended and execute the auto award process.)