# Did not get my bounty for accepted answer with 2 upvotes

Tags: bug, bounties

I answered a bounty question *after* a bounty was placed on it by another user (not the asker). I got 2 upvotes for it and it was accepted by the asker, but I did not get the bounty award after it expired (and the grace period too expired). Here's the post: [Eclipse Rulers background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441677/eclipse-rulers-background-color/13774856#13774856)

Note that I have read from the FAQ how bounty works, and I am asking this question because it is not working as described there.

Comment: Wow, its a downvote to me because the FAQ uses a vague term "approximately". Does 25 hours seem like "approximately" 24 hours? It doesn't to me.

Comment: BTW, though I didn't downvote, I'm willing to bet others did because you're complaining about not getting reputation. If you're going to do this it's always best to wait 24 hours to be sure that something is wrong (unless it's really obvious something is).

Comment: I did not complain about not getting reputation. It was only a question about how the bounty system works. I started complaining _after_ I got the downvotes. And by the way, if the oh-so-professional SO users did downvote because they perceived my question as a complaint, why couldn't they comment so? I believe the FAQ also mentions that as an etiquette somewhere. Don't throw stones at others when you stay in a glass house.

Comment: By the way, does anyone seriously think I care about my reputation points here on meta? Just Saying. No offence meant.

Comment: 'Does 25 hours seem like "approximately" 24 hours?' Yep, it sure does.

Comment: @Feathercrown Sure, a 4% difference is a pretty good "approximation".

Answer (score 7):

> **[Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577) twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period**, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.

The grace period ended an hour ago. You will soon get your share of the bounty.

### Update

You just got awarded with the bounty of 50 rep for that question, 26 hours after the bounty expired (and 2 hours after the grace period ended).

Comment: Pieces of eight! Squawk!

Comment: 24 hours grace period after the bounty expired, and further 2 hours grace period after the grace period expired. Wow. 26 is 8.33% greater than 24. Doesn't sound like a good approximation to me. :)

Comment: @ap.: There is probably a batch running that awards the bounties. And it doesn't seem to run every few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just let them make that clear in the FAQ. "Approximately" doesnt really tell anything. The batch could potentially run once a day, meaning in the worst case 48 hours is "approximately" 24 hours! Is it really that hard to say "Awarding the bounty could take up to 6 hours after the grace period ends"? There should be an option to downvote the FAQ as well.

Comment: It's _"on the close order of" 24 hours_, i.e. it's within an order of magnitude; you should get it within the week :-).

Comment: I don't care if it is a year or a century, or for that matter, if I don't get the points at all (after all it wasn't a very high quality answer). Just avoid writing vague statements in the FAQ, especially if it is easy to do so. Regardless, there should be a downvote option on the FAQ, so that such vague statements can get corrected.

Comment: @MaskedMan That's what meta is for. ;) Either they'll change it, or other people will clarify.

Comment: @Feathercrown Eh, no, that's not what meta is for. People read the FAQ, they believe what is written there, they don't go searching every post on meta to see if there is a "correction" there somewhere.

Comment: @MaskedMan You don't go looking for corrections, you go looking for CLARIFICATION. If something's vague, chances are, you can look it up on Meta.