# How long is a question unable to be closed after the grace period expires?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, bounties, expired-bounty

I'd like to close-vote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26807304/656243) as off-site resource request, but can't, due to a bounty. The bounty has expired, and the grace period has ended, so it seems reasonable that the question can be closed voted.

1. How long until it can be closed, after the grace period ends?
2. Is there a reason why this period (post-grace lock on cv'ing) exists?

I can't find any reference to this in the [How Do Bounties Work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/161974) FAQ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once the grace period expires, there is some delay between that event and when the system attempts to automatically award the bounty. Once the system makes that attempt and either decides a user to receive half or just drops the bounty, the bounty notice will be removed from the question and you will be able to vote to close the question again.

There's no *exact* timeframe of when this will happen. Simplest answer: you can vote to close once the bounty notice is completely gone.

Comment: Can you give me a magnitude? It's obviously not seconds. Is it minutes, hours, or days?

Comment: If I had to guess, 1-2 hours. I don't know what the schedule is for that bounty auto-awarding script to run.

Comment: If anyone can affirm that the delay is expressed in hours, I'll mark this answer accepted.

Comment: Well, the [last time I explained this on a similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147577), it took the system another 1 hour and 32 minutes to auto-award after the bounty expired.

Comment: In fact, as we speak, the bounty is now removed from the question you wanted to close.