# Automatic bounty is not awarded to an accepted answer

Tags: support, bug, reputation, bounties, accepted-answer

If I recall correctly I answered the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28720819/730807) during bounty period and it was accepted as answer during that period.

According to this [meta link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/232257):

> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the
>   bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be
>   awarded automatically.
>
> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period,
>   that answer is awarded the bounty (provided that the answer was posted
>   during the bounty period). Answers accepted before the bounty period
>   are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is
>   awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be
>   eligible are:
>
> The answer must have been given after the bounty was started The
>   answer must have a score of at least +2 The answer must not have been
>   written by the bounty starter If two or more eligible answers have the
>   same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded
>   the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any
>   answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

When can I report this issue and validate this?

*Note:*

I could be wrong, but I would like to know what had happened.

***Update:***

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29891208/730807) is accepted as an answer during the bounty period and the bounty was offered by questioner himself.

But I am not auto awarded the bounty.

> This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from Piwwoli that
>   ended yesterday. Grace period has ended
>
> This question has not received enough attention.

Here is the [chronology revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29601279/revisions) of the question

Thanks

Comment: oh ! Is that right ?

Comment: Although the wording is actually pretty clear that it must be a +2 score, is the +2 score really required. If a user awards the answer and the topic doesnt have much interest is the awarded answer not satisfactory for the posting user? I would like to say that the answer must not have a negative score as this implies the accepted answer is not a reasonable answer and the question has other interests? I am sure this could be debated and an algorithm evolved against others answers but was just curious.

Comment: @Nico: *Although the wording is actually pretty clear that it must be a +2 score* – I would not say so. The +2 score is only mentioned in the part starting with *otherwise.*

Comment: @Duraiamuthan.H: If your account is correct, you have found a bug and the default way to report this is to ask a question here that is tagged *bug* (i.e., simply tag your question with [tag:bug]).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - Yes , you are correct ! Thanks for clarifying the bug !

Comment: Re your latest update: looks like you got the bounty. See my answer on [a different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147577) for an explanation on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's if the *bounty starter* accepted an answer. In this case, the bounty starter was not the owner of the question - it was just some other user. So it's not possible that they would have accepted an answer during that period because they don't own the question.

Comment: Is it possible that I can verify via Stack Exchange Data Explorer ? like was the question offered a bounty by some other person or questioner himself ?

Comment: You can see who offered it in the [revision history for the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28720819/revisions).

Comment: If this can confuse someone like Martijn, perhaps it would be best to clarify the wording?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: the wording is there, I just glossed over it: *If the **bounty starter** accepted an answer during the bounty period*.

Comment: @animuson - Can you check my update on the question , Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wouldn't hurt to spell it out though: *If the bounty starter **is also the question asker and** accepted an answer during the bounty period...*

Comment: @starsplusplus: it's more that I forgot to check who started the bounty there.