# Time before bounty awarded automatically

Tags: support, bounties

I have seen several posts regarding bounty awarding (it is going to be my first bounty awarded, so pretty excited) and I understand from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period) that I should wait until the bounty notice disappears to receive it. My question is simply, is there a time of the day that the system checks for it? Or is it more periodical, like every hour?

**Edit** Now that there is a bounty on this post, perhaps we can check directly what is the behavior, if someone is so kind as to write an answer

Comment: Once the grace period is over and your answer qualifies for the 1/2 bounty, there's a check that runs periodically (not sure when) to check if your answer qualifies.

Comment: @AndrewLi This time seems to be also existing when your answer was accepted. Time to award it seems in my case to have taken between 1 and 2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check for bounties runs once an hour. Just looking at data here, all automatic awards seem to take between 1 and 2 hours from when the bounty ended to occur. I honestly don't know why there's always an extra hour delay; there must be an explicit check that is an hour off somewhere (as in the script that checks eligibility for auto-award seems to be looking for questions that have had the bounty an hour longer than when the grace period actually runs out).

Comment: Very good answer, thank you for your contribution