# What happens if a bounty is awarded automatically when there are 2 answers with an equal amount of upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, bounties, up-votes

From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/678412:

> #### What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?
>
> [Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577)
>   24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period
>   ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the
>   bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was
>   posted after the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full
>   bounty.
>
> Otherwise, either all or half of the bounty will be awarded to the
>   highest-scored answer among those which meet *all* of the following:
>
> - They were posted *after* the bounty was started, and
> - They have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
> - They were not written by the bounty starter.
>
> If the chosen answer was accepted by the question owner, it will
>   receive the full bounty. Otherwise, it will receive half the bounty.
>   If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is
>   chosen.
>
> If no answer meets any of the above two criteria, the bounty is not
>   awarded to any answer, and is *not* refunded to the bounty starter.

But what happens if a bounty is awarded automatically when there are 2 (or more) answers with an equal amount of upvotes? In such a case there is no "highest-scored answer" but rather "highest-scored answers".

Comment: It's in the FAQ: *If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is chosen.*

Comment: Just noticed that even my cited text contains this sentence. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [help-center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen.

The oldest answer gets half the bounty.